# Eclipse xtext- Xml grammar

Tags: xml, eclipse, xtext

I am writing a project using Eclipse xtext framework. I want to make a grammar for XML language.

How can I parse open and close tags ?

When I give something like this:

> `Body: '<'Type'>''</'type=[Type]'>';`
>
> `Type: name=ID;`

It allows to have tags like that:

> `<foo></foo>`
>   `<bar></foo>`

I would like to have only the possibility like that:

> `<foo></foo>`
>   `<bar></bar>`

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just parse any identifier in the closing tag and do a validation after parsing.

```
Element : 
  '<' type=[Type] '>
    children+=Element*
  '</' closingTagName=ID '>';
```

You'd also need to adjust content assist accordingly.